# TFS Build server Create packages Web Apps in solution without attempting to deploy

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, msbuild

When targeting a solution file to build with the default template I want the msbuild task to create packages for the web apps in the solution but not try to deploy them.

I had the following element in my project files along with the corresponding publish details for the various configurations we have in the solution.  This was both packaging the web apps and deploying them.

`<DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>`

I no longer want them to be published at this point but still want them to be packaged as before.  Is there something like the below that I can replace the deploy element with that will do what I want?

```
<PackageOnBuild>true</PackageOnBuild>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so seems I was thinking about this all wrong.

We still want to use the DeployOnBuild element and in addition add the DeployTarget element.

```
<DeployOnBuild>true</DeployOnBuild>
<DeployTarget>Package</DeployTarget>
<DeployIisAppPath>Iis Application Name</DeployIisAppPath>
```

Also adding the DeployIisAppPath populates the setparameters.xml.  Nice!